# Setting Alarms on devices with multiple users

Tags: alarmmanager, android-alarms

My app fails on android 5.1 version devices with the error below.
How do we handle this case where the device is possibly configured with multiple users?

java.lang.SecurityException: get application info: Neither user 1510130 nor current process has android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS.
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
    at android.app.IAlarmManager$Stub$Proxy.set(IAlarmManager.java:244)
    at android.app.AlarmManager.setImpl(AlarmManager.java:425)
    at android.app.AlarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.java:373)

Comment: Have you found out what was root cause area? I'm facing similar error but I cannot reproduce it. Unfortunately I have only logs from client.